# Day name with I18n

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-i18n

Without translation, this would get me today's day name:

```
Date.today.strftime("%A")
```

How would I localize it?

I.e. "Mardi" if `I18n.locale` is set to `fr`.

Comment: Have you considered using a library such as moment to handle this instead of I18n?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You probably have in your locale file(s) the following:

```
# example with fr
fr:
  date:
    day_names: [Dimanche, Lundi, Mardi, Mercredi, Jeudi, Vendredi, Samedi]
#               ^^^^^^^^ a week starts with a Sunday, not a Monday
```

In order to get today's name, you could do:

```
week_day = Date.today.wday # Returns the day of week (0-6, Sunday is zero)
I18n.t('date.day_names')[week_day]
```

or eventually

```
I18n.l(Date.today, format: '%A')
```

Answer (score 11):

```
l Date.today, format: "%A"
```

Will work if you have the `day_names` in your translation file.

Answer (score 0):

if you use [`rails-i18n`](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n), you will have the day names and month names already translated, e.g.:

```rb
I18n.l(value, format: "le %A %e %B à %-Hh%M")
# le Dimanche 19 Juillet à 21h00
```